# QGIS 3.4 Layout manager, attribute table, scale of map

Tags: qgis-3, attribute-table, print-composer, scale, layout-manager

I am trying to produce maps faster than I currently do. I was thinking to use the "show only features visible within a map" option. I already use it for the coordinates table and I am trying to add more attribute tables in it such as the map's information.

In the attribute table, I can not store the Map 1 scale. Of course I can use the scale bar option, style>numeric which is automatically changing the scale number, but I hope to find out something...I don't know, something in order with my map style.

If I use the scale bar I have to customize it to look like it is in order with the information's attribute table, or I have to place it somewhere else within my map. I have uploaded a picture of my project, the only thing that is missing is the scale number.

Is there any expression that autofills the map scale value? The result will be, when I have to draw 5,10,100 polygons, while I finish the polygon creation I will fill the attributes table and later use the layout manager to export maps faster, or use atlas.

[image]

Comment: Is your end goal to store the layout map scale in the attribute table? Or is it to display the map scale on the layout?

Comment: It does sound like the atlas feature would improve your workflow. Have you tried it yet?

Comment: Yes I have tried Atlas, it is nice, but there I have another problem with neighbouring polygons which appear in Map1 area and fill the coordinate table with XY that I don't want. It would be nice to have the scale in the attribute table, although now I understand it is impossible because I want to add dynamic data in a static attribute table.I am thinking to add the scale in the Attribute table and connect it with the layout scale editor,most of my maps are in 1/500 or 1/1000, if I notice something unfitting I will go and change manually the scale from the attribute table.